# How to generate RelationalPath Derived class using QueryDsl Maven plugin?

Tags: java, querydsl

I've generated EntityBasePath derived classes of my entities using the QueryDsl maven plugin. But I want that the plugin generate classes that derived from RelationalPath of the QueryDsl class to use it in the DML operations. How can I do this thing?

Comment: Are you using annotated types as the source?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper My scenario is using both QueryDsl jpa adapter and QueryDsl sql in Spring data. the generated files is extended EntityPath, and when I want to use them for example in InsertClause, I can't because it need RelationalPath derived classes

Comment: You can't turn it into a RelationalPath automatically, because Querydsl is not able to turn the JPA mapping info into RelationalPath SQL mapping info.

Answer (score 3):

As @Timo Westkämper feedback  You can't turn it into a RelationalPath automatically

but you can create RelationalPathBase using your  entityPath

```
RelationalPathBase relationalPathBase= new RelationalPathBase(this.entityPath.getType(), this.entityPath.getMetadata(), "yourSchemaName","yourTableName");
```